# What does std::mutex prevent threads from modifying?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

What part of memory gets locked by `mutex` when `.lock()` or `.try_lock()`, is it just the function or is it the whole program that gets locked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is locked except the mutex.  Everything else continues running (until it tries to lock an already locked mutex that is).  The mutex is only there so that two threads cannot run the code between a mutex lock and a mutex unlock at the same time.

Comment: The idea that we use a mutex to protect a block of code is a bit off. Code doesn't need protection. We use a mutex to protect the _shared data_ that a block of code operates on. The distinction becomes important when there's more than one block of code in the system that operates on the same shared data. The mutex only offers protection if every block of code that accesses the same data first locks the same mutex.

Comment: I intentionally phrased it that way to emphasize that there's nothing special linking a mutex to the data that you want to protect.  You have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

A mutex doesn't really lock anything, except for itself.  You can think of a mutex as being a gate where you can only unlock it from the inside.  When the gate is locked, any thread that tries to lock the mutex will sit there at the gate and wait for the current thread that is behind the gate to unlock it and let them in.  When they gate is not locked then when you call `lock` you can just go in, close and lock the gate, and now no threads can get past the gate until you unlock it and let them in.

Comment: Re, "now no threads can get past the gate." If you're going to use that analogy, then you ought to point out that a locked gate doesn't keep anybody out of the area if there's another gate near by that isn't locked. A mutex only is effective at protecting data when _every bit of code_ that access the data locks the same mutex first.

Answer (score 1):

A mutex doesn't lock anything. You just *use* a mutex to communicate to other parts of your code that they should consider whatever *you* decide needs to be protected from access by several threads at the same time to be off-limits for now.

You could think of a mutex as something like a boolean `okToModify`. Whenever you want to edit something, you check if `okToModify` is `true`. If it is, you set it to `false` (preventing any other threads from modifying it), change it, then set `okToModify` back to `true` to tell the other threads you're done and give them a chance to modify:

```
// WARNING! This code doesn't actually work as a lock!
//    it is just an example of the concept.
struct LockedInt {
    bool okToModify; // This would be your mutex instead of a bool.
    int integer;
};

struct LockedInt myLockedInt = { true, 0 };    

...

while (myLockedInt.okToModify == false)
    ; // wait doing nothing until whoever is modifying the int is done.
myLockedInt.okToModify = false; // Prevent other threads from getting out of while loop above.
myLockedInt.integer += 1;
myLockedInt.okToModify = true; // Now other threads get out of the while loop if they were waiting and can modify.
```

The while loop and `okToModify = false` above is basically what locking a mutex does, and `okToModify = true` is what unlocking a mutex does.

Now, why do we need mutexes and don't use booleans? Because a thread could be running at the same time as those three lines above. The code for locking a mutex actually guarantees that the waiting for `okToModify` to become `true` and setting `okToModify = false` happen in one go, and therefore no other thread can get "in between the lines", for example by using a special machine-code instruction called "compare-and-exchange".

So **do *not* use booleans instead of mutexes**, but you *can* think of a mutex as a special, thread-safe boolean.

Comment: Answer would be better if the code example started with a comment: `// This doesn't actually work.` Examples of things that one should not do, or examples (like yours) of how things almost-but-not-quite-actually work can be useful, but one must be very careful when showing them to beginners that the beginner does not get the wrong idea.

Comment: i heard rumors of ppl copying code from SO answers and using it without understanding what it actually does ;)

Comment: Sometimes people copy the code without understanding ANYTHING.

Comment: I've added a comment and emphasized the sentiment at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`m.lock()` doesn't really lock *anything.* What it does is, it *waits* to take *ownership* of the mutex. A mutex always either is *owned* by exactly one thread or else it is *available*.  `m.lock()` waits until the mutex becomes available, and then it takes ownership of it in the name of the calling thread.

`m.unlock` *releases* the mutex (i.e., it relinquishes ownership), causing the mutex to once again become available.

---

Mutexes also perform another very important function. In modern C++, when some thread T performs a sequence of assignments of various values to various memory locations, the system makes no guarantees about when other threads U, V, and W will see those assignments, whether the other threads will see the assignments happen in the same order in which thread T performed them, or even, whether the other threads will *ever* see the assignments.

There are some quite complicated rules governing things that a programmer can do to ensure that different threads see a consistent view of shared memory objects (Google "C++ memory model"), but here's one simple rule:

Whatever thread T did before it releases some mutex M is guaranteed to be visible to any other thread U *after* thread U subsequently locks the same mutex M.

Comment: The rules are not "complicated", they are inexistant. Or useless if you assume sequential behavior, which is inevitable if you are going to have any well defined program.